# what will be order of execution of this sql join query

Tags: mysql

I want to know the execution order of the following join query

```
     SELECT L.LOGIN_NAME, U.USER_FIRST_NAME AS 'FIRST NAME'
     ,U.USER_LAST_NAME AS 'LAST NAME'
     ,L.LOGIN_FAILED_ATTEMPTS AS 'FAILED ATTEMPTS'
     FROM login_t L   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN user_t U ON U.LOGIN_NAME=L.login_name 
     AND L.LOGIN_PWD = pwd
     INNER JOIN SETTINGS_T S ON S.SETTING_NAME='LOGIN_ATTEMPTS' 
     WHERE L.LOGIN_NAME = login_name 
     AND L.LOGIN_FAILED_ATTEMPTS < S.SETTING_VALUE;
```

Comment: queries are atomic. there is no real "order of operations". you run the query and get a result. or do you mean the order the join/where/order/etc... portions are applied?

Comment: i mean order at which tables will be accessed in join query

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT L.LOGIN_NAME, ...` to find out what the MySQL DBMS will do with your query. See the [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for how to interpret the information it will give you.